# configuring multiple values to a yml property in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

markets: india,singapore,vietnam,UK,malta,oman

In my spring boot project, there are two configurations (shown above) in the `application.yml` file.

value of `market.url` is different for different region countries for example, for `india,singapore,vietnam` it is `url1` and for `UK,malta,oman` it is `url2`.

I have a third party jar (for which I do not have code access) which uses the configuration '`market.url`' .

My question is how can I configure multiple values for `market.url` so that the third party code gets correct value according to the market which comes with every request.

Comment: Technically, it is possible to override the value of "market.url" but don't know how your third party will use it.

There should be some way to change it on your third party.

Comment: how can i override 'market.url' in my code (like some filter) if yes then for each request i will identify the correct url and override 'market.url' before third party code gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it two ways: the first one is using a small yml configuration this way :

```
marker:
  first:
    url: url1
    countries: india,singapore,vietnam
  second:
    url: url2
    countries: UK,malta,oman
```

And then create your configuration Beans and create some kind of in memory repository that will hold all the configuration beans and return url1 or url2 depending on the country.

The second way which is less maintainable but more straightforward, is using a yml configuration in this format :

```
marker:
  india:
    url: url1
  malta:
    url: url2
  ...
```

then create the Bean for this configuration and use it directly.
I hope this helps

Comment: i can do this but with this approach key will be changed like 'market.first.url' or in second case 'market.india.url' which i can not do..Key needs to be 'market.url' only.

Comment: Can't you use a java object in your third party libarary instead of using the key ?